# View not found in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I use asp.net core 2.2 and make a web application

my application working fine on Localhost, but after publish and upload on my server getting Internal Server Error when I want to access areas route.

I get the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The view 'Login' was not found. The following locations were searched:
/Areas/Admin/Views/Account/Login.cshtml
/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/Login.cshtml
/Views/Shared/Login.cshtml
/Pages/Shared/Login.cshtml
```

but `Login.cshtml`  exist in `/Areas/Admin/Views/Account/`

Comment: I think when you published it, you didn't include the `.cshtml` file in the publish.

Comment: @Dai another views working fine

Comment: And nothing odd about the permissions?